# triger ajax call after every 24 hours in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how can i trigger Jquery ajax call after the every 24 hours?

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.post('get_sales.php', function(data) {
        $('#updates_contents').html(data);
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Is someone really going to have that browser window open for 24 hours?  If you're wanting run something every 24 hours, there's probably a better way depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yes the browser window will open everyday all the time..

Comment: Have you heard about cronjobs ??

Comment: Why not just use a cron task instead; no need to worry about somebody inadvertently shutting down the browser or the client desktop, or automatic updates that restart the desktop, or power outages or any of a myriad of happenstances

Comment: i am newbie for this talk mark. i don't know how to work on cron job.

Comment: you are working on which platform i mean operating system??

Comment: is there any alternate way as for eg: to fetch the system date using jquery and trigger function after specific time period.

Comment: i am working on window 7..

Comment: wamp server i am using..

Comment: If you're on a windows server, then it's "Scheduled Tasks" from the admin menu

Comment: but my web app will run in the android tv browser..

Comment: Letting any application (as a browser) opens 24/24 7/7 is calling for trouble regarding memory leaks

Comment: amm... but wolf i want the solution to how we can send the ajax request after 24 hour.. can u help me..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with jQuery and PHP, you can do the following:

```
//var intervalTime = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //refresh every 1 day
var intervalTime = 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //refresh every 1 hour
//the format is HOUR * MINUTE * SECONDS * MILI-SECOND.

function refresher() {
     $.post('get_sales.php', function(data) {
        $('#updates_contents').html(data);
    });
}
var timerID;
function start() {
     //you might want to refresh the content when the widget first loads then uncomment the following line
     //refresher();
     //and then set interval to refresh it later on
     timerID = setInterval("refresher", intervalTime );
 }

//if something went wrong, user can click on refresh button which can call this function
function refreshBtnClick() { 
      clearTimeout(timerID ); 
      start();
}
start();
```

Remember to add a button to manually refresh the content suppose in case, automation failed. 1 hour refresh time will give you better results. Remember A. Wolff's comment about memory leaks.

Comment: thnx hardik.. i am using your above code. but it immediately send the ajax on load of the window...
i am using inside this block..
$(document).ready(function() {
// your code
});

Comment: i want to call this above function after 1 hour... how can i do it.?

Comment: edited the answer, now it wont call the ajax on load. It would be good, if you read the comments and try to understand the code instead of just copy-pasting it.

Comment: i was implemented your previous script. it gives the Reference Error As: 
"ReferenceError: refrehser is not defined
timerID = setInterval("refrehser", intervalTime );"

Comment: and thnax for ur concern sir.. now i change my code.. will let u know if it runs..:)

Comment: I have fixed the typo, now should work properly. You are welcome, accept the answer if it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on android TV app, you might just want to look at:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

Setting up a JS timer in browser and keep running your app 24/7 waiting for the timeout to occur is not practical.
Instead you can find a work around, like creating a scheduler class which refresh the content every 24 hours and stores it locally, which your browser just refresh the content from local db or file.

Comment: I read in your comments "but my web app will run in the android tv browser.. ", your backend might be in php, but if your frontend is in android tv, you might consider using an extra layer of service to update the content.

Comment: but i have not worked in android... i am php developer.